# how to set date dynamically on Ultra-light jQuery calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am using Ultra-light jQuery calendar to display calendar pagination. I am unable to set the date dynamically when the page loads.

There is no documentation for this plugin. Please help me to fix this issue

https://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/04/06/ultra-light-jquery-calendar/

for more references.

http://bugsvoice.com/applications/bugsVoice/site/test/calendarPickerDemo.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the date with the function changeDate

```
var dateSelector;
$(function(){
  dateSelector=$("#calendarFilterBox").calendarPicker({});
  dateSelector.changeDate(new Date("August 13, 1983"));
});
```